# Limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is a question from my homework. Please help me!

The question is to find:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{ 7^n}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use this fact: $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} a^n = 0 $$ if $|a| < 1$ (proof?). Also, notice $$\frac{2^{n+1}}{7^n} = 2\left(\frac{2}{7}\right)^n $$

Comment: i think you need to wait couple of minutes..

Comment: i still cannot accept your answer, it keeps saying that "you can accept an answer in 9 minutes", but 9 minutes have passed away so long ago

Answer (score 0):

Set $a_n=\frac{2^{n+1}}{7^n}$ and consider the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$.  Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{2}{7}<1$,  by root test we obtain that the series is convergent. Hence general term of the series goes to zero, i.e,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2^{n+1}}{7^n}=0$.